# what does light bounce off of? electons? the atom itself?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am wondering this because I'm researching a way to create a seemingly "solid wall" that you can pass through.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Light mainly interacts with the electron(s) in the atom.